# Generate a list and return to view from Linq

Tags: c#, list, asp.net-mvc-4, listview, razor

i want to generate a list from query and show on view but it shows me the error as below, what's the mistakes that i've done?

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SurveyTool.Models.SURV_Question_Ext_Model]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SurveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel]'.

Edit.cshtml:

```
    @model List<SurveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count;i++ )
    {
        <table>

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Question_Ext)
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>

    }
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

SURV_AnsControllers :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Edit(int Survey_ID)
        {

               var model =from r in db.SURV_Question_Ext_Model
                         join s in db.SURV_Question_Model
                         on r.Qext_Question_ID equals
                         s.Question_ID
                         where s.Question_Survey_ID == Survey_ID
                         orderby s.Question_Position ascending
                         select r;

            return View(model.ToList());
        }
```

AnswerQuestionViewModel:

```
public class AnswerQuestionViewModel
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int Survey_ID { get; set; }

        public virtual List<SURV_Question_Ext_Model> Question_Ext { get; set; }
        public string Questions { get; set; }
        public string Answer_Data { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your view is expecting a model that is a list while your controller method is only returning a single instance of the model.

Did you try returning a list instead?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int Survey_ID)
{
    AnswerQuestionViewModel mymodel = new AnswerQuestionViewModel();
    var myList = new List<AnswerQuestionViewModel>();
    mymodel.Survey_ID = Survey_ID;
    myList.Add(mymodel);
    return View(myList);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback, how can i return a list result by query?

Comment: You're returning the wrong list.  Instead of returning View(model.ToList()), you need to create a new List<AnswerQuestionViewModel>() and a new AnswerQuestionViewModel object like I showed in my answer. Thenset the Question_Ext property of the AnswerQuestionViewModel object and add it to the list. Set that list to the result of your query.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in a single view model to Razor. Change:

```
@model List<urveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel>
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Question_Ext[i].Qext_Text)
```

To:

```
@model urveyTool.Models.AnswerQuestionViewModel
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Question_Ext[i].Qext_Text)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Question_Ext[i].Qext_Text)
```

The hidden input tag will get used to post data back to the controller.